# How to restrict to a one letter input?

Tags: c

I realised that if the input is a word starting with 'y' or 'n', it will escape the loop. How can I restrict the loop such that it will continue looping unless the input is a single character?

```
do
{
    printf("Do you want to try again? (Y/N): ");
    fflush(stdin);                              
    scanf("%c", &repeat);
    repeat = toupper(repeat);
    if (repeat != 'Y' && repeat != 'N')         
        printf("Invalid answer. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n");

} while (repeat != 'N' && repeat != 'Y');
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `repeat`?

Comment: You need to [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how a two-character input is different from two one-character inputs one right after another.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char repeat[3] = {0};//3 : one character + one character + NUL
    do{
        printf("Do you want to try again? (Y/N): ");fflush(stdout);
        if(EOF==scanf("%2s", repeat)){ *repeat = 'N'; break; }
        *repeat = toupper(*repeat);
        if (repeat[1] || *repeat != 'Y' && *repeat != 'N'){//repeat[1] != '\0'..     
            printf("Invalid answer. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");//clear upto newline
            *repeat = 0;
        }
    } while (*repeat != 'N' && *repeat != 'Y'); 
    puts("Bye!");//try agein or see ya, bye
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UB if EOF was entered.

Comment: @alk If `EOF` was entered, you should leave the loop?

Comment: "*... leave the loop?*": I do not know, as the specification for this case is missing by the OP, but definitely don't do `... toupper(*repeat)`. As `*repeat` is uninitialised, at least for the 1st iteration.

Comment: Perhaps just do `char repeat[3] = {0};`?

Comment: I decided to exit the loop. thank you for the advice.

Comment: I do not know the feelings of the people to enter the EOF. but maybe I think player want to quit, 
So, to `*repeat = 'N'; break;` it might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using `scanf()` one can use `fgets()` to read a line and then do the parsing one self:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void)
{
  char repeat = '\0';

  do
  {
    int input_valid = 0; /* Be pessimistic. */
    char line[3] = {0};

    puts("Do you want to try again? (Y/N):");

    do /* On-time loop, to break out on parsing error. */
    {
      if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
      {
        break; /* Either fgets() failed or EOF was read. Start over ... */
      }

      if (line[1] != '\0' && line[1] != '\n') 
      {
        break; /* There was more then one character read. Start over ... */
      }

      line[0] = toupper(line[0]);

      if (line[0] != 'Y' && line[0] != 'N') 
      {      
        break; /* Something else but Y or N was read. Start over ... */
      }

      input_valid = 1;
    } while (0);

    if (input_valid == 0)
    {
      int c;

      do /* Flush rest of input. if any. */
      {
        c = getc(stdin);
      } while (EOF != c && '\n' != c);

      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid answer. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
      repeat = line[0];
    }
  } while ('\0' == repeat);

  printf("The user entered: '%c'\n", repeat); /* Will only print either Y or N. */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think that there is a need to clear the input buffer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Just fixed this implicitly by moving the definition of `repeat` (along with its initialisation)  to the least necessary scope. :-)

Comment: try `Yes, I do.` enter. Also `} while (input_valid == 0)` <-- forgot `;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Cleaned -up and re-arranged a bit more... - cannot reproduce this `Yes, I do.` issue.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: How would `Ye` pass this `if (line[1] != '\0' && line[1] != '\n')`?

Answer (score 0):

First `fflush(stdin);` does not make sense except in Microsoft's world.

Then, the scanf family function returns a value which is the number of input token successfully decoded and that return value should **always** be controlled. And %c should be used with caution because it can return a blank character (space or newline) remaining in buffer while %s only return printable characters. With those remarks you code could become:

```
repeat = '\0';
do
{
    char dummy[2], inp[2];
    printf("Do you want to try again? (Y/N): ");
    // fflush(stdin);                              
    if (1 == scanf("%1s%1s", inp,dummy) repeat = toupper(inp[0]);
    if (repeat != 'Y' && repeat != 'N')         
        printf("Invalid answer. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n");

} while (repeat != 'N' && repeat != 'Y');
```